# Trigger.isExecuting value from Apex Class

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, triggercontext

As per the documentation, trigger.isExecuting returns true if the current context for the Apex code is a trigger, not a Visualforce page, a Web service, or an executeanonymous() API call.

I am a bit confused by this. If VF page calls a controller function which makes an DML operation firing the trigger, what would be the value of isExecuting in that case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In brief `Trigger.isExecuting` determines if the context is trigger or Visualforce. If it returns true context is trigger otherwise context is Visualforce or other.
In your case `Trigger.isExecuting` will return `true`.

Simple ex:

Create a class:

```
public class TriggerContextDemo
{
  public Boolean updateContact(Contact[] conList)
  {
     // Will not update contact if method is called in TriggerContext
     if(Trigger.isExecuting)
     {
        // Do Not Update Any contact
        System.debug(' $ $ NOT updating contacts');
     }
     else
     {
       // update contacts
       System.debug(' $ $ updating contacts');
     }
     System.debug(' $ $ return ' + Trigger.isExecuting);
     return Trigger.isExecuting;
  }
}
```

Now Create a trigger on Contact

```
trigger ContextCheckTrigger on Contact (before insert, before update) {
   TriggerContextDemo demo = new TriggerContextDemo();
   demo.updateContact(Trigger.New);
}
```

Now if any of Contact's record is updated or inserted by Visualforce Controller or manually  it will fire a trigger and in the trigger instance method of `TriggerContextDemo` is called and  result in System.debugs:

> $ $ NOT updating contacts // Because Trigger.isExecuting is true
>
> $ $ return true // Trigger Context exist

If we call the same class from Developer console's execute Anonymous like this:

```
TriggerContextDemo cc = new TriggerContextDemo();
cc.updateContact(null);
```

In this case same class will result in system.debugs:

> $ $ updating contacts
>
> $ $ return false  // No trigger context

Comment: So even though if the starting point of the execution was not a trigger (a visualforce controller in my case)  which in turns results in a trigger execution, isExecuting will be true?

Comment: @RajeshShah Yes, because DML operation is firing a trigger which will result a trigger context.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Regal's answer, the value can be change within the same action. For example, if you have a visualforce action that performs DML within the action method Trigger.isExecuting will be *false*, but within triggers invoked by the DML this action causes Trigger.isExecuting will be *true*.

To demonstrate let's set up a class with a static string variable we can write to from the controller action *and* the trigger we invoke:

```
public class MyPageController{
    public static String log = '';

    public PageReference doSomeDML(){
        log += 'Starting doSomeDML(); - Trigger.isExecuting = '+Trigger.isExecuting+'\n';
        insert new Contact(LastName = 'Dummy contact');
        return null;
    }

    public String getLog(){
        return log;
    }
}
```

We'll also create a trigger on contact that writes to MyPageController.log:

```
trigger ContactLogTrigger on Contact (before insert) {
    System.debug('Log state is: '+ MyPageController.log);
    MyPageController.log += 'In trigger ContactLogTrigger - Trigger.isExecuting = '+Trigger.isExecuting+'\n';
}
```

And finally a page to display the results:

```
<apex:page controller="MyPageController" action="{!doSomeDML}" sidebar="false">
    Log for doSomeDML: <br />
    <pre>{!log}</pre>
</apex:page>
```

If you run this page you'll see Trigger.isExecuting is different within the same transaction depending on if you're in a trigger or not:

[image]

Comment: Thats a wonderful example which clears all the doubts I had. Thanks for your time on this.